# Questions on Nature of graph

Tags: calculus, inequality

While playing with inequalities on desmos, I found out an inequality $$\frac {|\sin2x|}{2πe}\le \left|\tan(\ln(x))\right|$$

Whose solutions occur after an indefinite interval then they disappear for some interval and occurs again.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Is there any reason why solutions disappears after such long intervals. Can we find solutions without using graph?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the nature of $\tan(\ln(x))$. It is piecewise increasing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in the disjoint ranges $\left(e^{(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}}, e^{(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)\; k\in\mathbb{Z}$. It thus has infinite roots, namely $e^{k\pi}$, in each of the previously mentioned disjoint ranges, somewhat similar to $\tan(x)$. But instead of being equally spaced, these ranges widen out exponentially as $x$ increases. Also, these shrink exponentially towards zero, i.e. infinitely many progressively smaller ranges appear towards zero, which means that for any $x^*>0$, we have infinite roots in $(0, x^*)$.
Now $|\tan(\ln(x))|$ in these disjoint ranges decreases from $\infty$ to zero at its root and then increases back to $\infty$, i.e. piecewise monotonic.

Now consider $\frac{|\sin(2x)|}{2\pi e}$. In each of the infinite intervals $\left[n\frac{\pi}{2}, (n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, it increases from zero, attains a maximum of $\frac{1}{2\pi e}$ and then decreases back to zero. Let us pick a subset of these intervals:
$$\left[\;\;\left\lfloor\frac{2e^{k\pi}}{\pi}\right\rfloor\frac{\pi}{2}, \;\;\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2e^{k\pi}}{\pi}\right\rfloor+1\right)\frac{\pi}{2}\;\;\right]$$
One can check that $e^{k\pi}$ is always inside this interval and thus we have two intersections (of these two curves) in each such range around this root $e^{k\pi}$, (one in the decreasing and one in the increasing branch of $|\tan(\ln(x))|$) **and between these, but not only here, there is a disappearance of this inequality**.

Where else is there a disappearance? Consider consecutive ranges of length $\frac{\pi}{2}$ before and after this range. As $|\tan(\ln(x))|$ rises both ways from zero, there maybe intervals where it remains below $\frac{1}{2\pi e}$, and in such an interval again we have two intersections and thus a disappearance. So such disappearance ranges appear in clusters around the stated intervals, such as around the green one here: $\left(340\frac{\pi}{2}, 341\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.\

[image]

By the way, Desmos is approximating and skipping points here: this green band does have intersection points, i.e. red bands of satisfiability inside as well. Can see zoomed in at these end points
as well.

[image]
[image]

It is clearly difficult to analytically express these solutions in closed form but what we can see is that these ranges (in the middle of these clusters) which contain such disappearances also spread out exponentially. That is why each of these clusters of narrow bands of disappearance (each of which is certainly less than this range width i.e. $\frac{\pi}{2}$), appear after such long intervals